# How do i Have the array values saved outside the foreach loop

Tags: php

i have a foreach loop  when looping through  that I am creating a $data array which holds all values

```
foreach ($this->arr1['somevalue']['object'] as $record ){                
    $data_add = array(
    'CODE' => $record['CODE'],
    'some_key' => $this->arr['somevalue'],
    'lines' => count($this->arr['somevalue']['object'])    
    );
       }
       var_dump($data_add);
```

Now when I say var_dump($data_add) Iam getting only the last value for "CODE"  key .The above loop repeats for 3
   times That means i will have 3 values .But iam getting only the third value.1st and 2nd values are not displayed. 
   How  do i get the values.I have an idea saying creating an array(record['CODE']) but did not work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$data_add = array(
    'CODE' => $record['CODE'],
    'some_key' => $this->arr['somevalue'],
    'lines' => count($this->arr['somevalue']['object'])    
    );
```

to:

```
$data_add[] = array(
    'CODE' => $record['CODE'],
    'some_key' => $this->arr['somevalue'],
    'lines' => count($this->arr['somevalue']['object'])    
    );
```

Comment: @someone in case it wasn't obvious, your code doesn't work because you were overwriting the existing array each iteration of the loop. $array[] is sorta a shorthand for array_push

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($this->arr1['somevalue']['object'] as $record ){                
  $data_add[] = array(
    'CODE' => $record['CODE'],
    'some_key' => $this->arr['somevalue'],
    'lines' => count($this->arr['somevalue']['object'])    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you amend the code in order that `$data_add` becomes an array:

```
foreach ($this->arr1['somevalue']['object'] as $record ){                
    $data_add[] = array(
    'CODE' => $record['CODE'],
    'some_key' => $this->arr['somevalue'],
    'lines' => count($this->arr['somevalue']['object'])    
    );
       }
       var_dump($data_add);
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have is that you are overwriting the $data_add variable each iteration, and thus you only keep the last, to obtain all answers you could use an array (as proposed by the others)