# how to pass value of for loop from one page to next page in php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

hi everyone my problem is this that i dynamically creted rows of table on the basis user input. Now each row contain textbox,comboxbox on selcting value from combobox n entering value in textbox from first three column ,result will display.on passing these selected n entered value on next page only the last row values moves to next page .i want to pass all loop values to next page
javascripting code

```
<script>
 function getText3(row){
            var in1=document.getElementById('in1-' + row).value;
            var in2=document.getElementById('in2-' + row).value;
            var in4=document.getElementById('in4-' + row).value;
            var in3=(in1*in2*in4*30)/1000;
            document.getElementById('in3-' + row).value=in3.toFixed(2 );

    }

</script>
```

table code

```
<?php
$de=$_POST['text123'];
echo $de;
?>

<body>
<form action="kl2.php" method="post" >
       <table border="1" align="center" id="wr123">
    <tr>
        <th>WAS</th>
        <th>NO.</th>
        <th>AVERAGE</th>
        <th>APPROX</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $de; $i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Tube</td>
        <td>
            <select id="in4-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="t1" onclick="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" >
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="75">75</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="t2" id="in1-<?php echo $i; ?>" onblur="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="a1" id="in2-<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" >
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="in3-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="username" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />

    </table>
    </form>
```

kl2.php

```
<?php
@$a=$_POST['t1'];
echo @$a;
$sl = $_POST['t2'];
echo $sl;
$b=$_POST['a1'];
echo $b;
$c=$_POST['username'];
echo $c;
 ?>
```

on submit click it only display the last row values i.e if user enter 3 ,3 rows get displayed after clicking the submit only the data of last row display

Comment: Why do you need to pass a variable to Javascript? You could use a hidden field for that - plus, you could always count the number of available cells using Javascript

Comment: sory sir i cant get your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be passing an array, you can deal with it as an array in the PHP side.

To do this, in each input, change the name="X" to name="X[]"

Example:

```
        <input type="text" name="t2" id="in1-<?php echo $i; ?>" onblur="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" />
```

to:

```
        <input type="text" name="t2[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="in1-<?php echo $i; ?>" onblur="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" />
```

Also, it's generally a bad idea to use @'s in php to suppress errors.

Try something like:

```
  var_dump($_POST);
```

and you will see how the data comes through to you.

Hint:

```
if (isset($_POST['t1']) {
   $t1_data = $_POST['t1'];
}
```

** EDIT **

Try something like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $data_t1 = $_POST['t1'];
    foreach ($data_t1 as $key => $value) {

        echo 'T1: ' . $value . '<br />';
        echo 'T2: ' . $_POST['t2'][$key] . '<br />';
        echo 'Username: ' . $_POST['username'][$key] . '<br /><br />';

    }

}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function getText3(row){
            var in1=document.getElementById('in1-' + row).value;
            var in2=document.getElementById('in2-' + row).value;
            var in4=document.getElementById('in4-' + row).value;
            var in3=(in1*in2*in4*30)/1000;
            document.getElementById('in3-' + row).value=in3.toFixed(2 );

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<table border="1" align="center" id="wr123">
    <tr>
        <th>WAS</th>
        <th>NO.</th>
        <th>AVERAGE</th>
        <th>APPROX</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

    for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Tube</td>
        <td>
            <select id="in4-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="t1[<?php echo $i; ?>] onclick="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" >
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="75">75</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="t2[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="in1-<?php echo $i; ?>" onblur="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="a1[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="in2-<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" >
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="in3-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="username[<?php echo $i; ?>]" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by doing this its not display the value which i have enter it only display word array

Comment: Correct, it's an array. Loop over it using a foreach loop.

Comment: sir if u dont mind kindly tell me the exact way for display the all values on next page as i need all values for further computation

Comment: There you go. I've edited my answer. Please mark it as accepted (And the other previous question if you could)

Comment: thanks sir for your support i really appreciate your support n help

Comment: sir i paste my question here u know my thing from start nw how can i used for every row http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547840/how-do-i-have-the-array-values-saved-outside-the-foreach-loop

Comment: I don't understand I'm afraid. Can you elaborate with a new question? As it won't make sense in here.

Comment: sir i simply want that i get these all rows value for further computation